# Message not showing after user joins sometimes

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I made this chat module that shows a local message in the chat when a user joins, but sometimes when they join the message isn't there, but sometimes the message does appear. I think it's because the player didn't load fast enough? Is it possible to wait for the player to fully load before running the code for the message? I know you can wait for a player to join before running some code, but I don't know how I would do that in a module script (I've tried). Here's my script:

```
local function Run(ChatService)

local server = ChatService:AddSpeaker("Server")
server:JoinChannel("All")
local local_nick = nil

ChatService:GetChannel("All").SpeakerJoined:connect(function(speaker)
        spawn(function()        
            server:SayMessage(string.format("Hello %s, Welcome to Bailiann's F3X Building Place!",speaker),"All")
            server:SetExtraData("NameColor", Color3.new(
            150.0/255.0,
            167.0/255.0,
            255.0/255.0)
            )
            server:SetExtraData("ChatColor", Color3.new(
            249.0/255.0,
            207.0/255.0,
            249.0/255.0
            ))
        end)    
    end)
end
return Run
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the new roblox setCore() function, it only works in localscripts though. Here’s the code

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr)
wait() -- Sometimes this is required
game.StarterGui:SetCore("ChatMakeSystemMessage", {
Text = "Welcome to my game!"; -- Required. Has to be a string!
Color = Color3.new(0, 1, 1); -- Cyan is (0, 255 / 255, 255 / 255). Optional, defaults to white: Color3.new(255 / 255, 255 / 255, 243 / 255)
Font = Enum.Font.SourceSans; -- Optional, defaults to Enum.Font.SourceSansBold
FontSize = Enum.FontSize.Size24; -- Optional, defaults to Enum.FontSize.Size18
})

end)
```

Hopefully this helps, if not make sure to put the localscript in `Starter Player -> StarterPlayerScripts`